# How to find similar users by their vote

Tags: algorithm

In my forum, I have **m users** and **n questions** to vote. Users can skip a question or vote "yes" or "no" as the answer.

**How do I find out users with high similarity in an efficient way?**

e.g. How to find all users with more than 80% similarity for **all users**? I want to use it as my friend recommender system.

All I can think is to iterate over all user for each user to compare their vote. But this creates m² complexity.

Comment: What time complexity are you looking for then?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a solution with a linear complexity O(m), or anything better than O(m2)

Comment: What will be the upper bound on the values of ```m``` and ```n```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a simple k-means clustering algorithm? The computational complexity will still be O(m2), but there should be packages available for easy use.